# Laravel hasMany return null

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Category:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'keywords', 'slug'];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

And have model product:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

In table products I have product with column `category_id`. But return null. Why? I can't get products in current category with `$category->products`, because always empty. How I can fix this?

In model product relation `category` working, but on model `category` not working..

On table products I have cascade:

```
$table->foreign('category_id')
    ->references('id')->on('categories')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Can you show the migration of the `category` table please ?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are trying to access the `$category->products` relation?

Comment: Check that your 'category_id' in the products table is unsigned. eg. `$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate your definition

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'category_id');
```

You have error here because attach on catergories but it will be on products

```
$table->foreign('category_id')
    ->references('id')->on('products')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: please add more details to your answer

Comment: His mean you should try this for Category model `return $this->hasMany(Product::class, category_id);`

Comment: What exactly I mean one category have many products with foreign key category_Id but mistake you have it is on adding foreign key on categories

Answer (score 1):

Everything is right, just make changes in the products migration
change this code

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

to

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
->on('products'->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do following changes

1. Make change in product migration file (in products table)

   ```
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('category_id')->on('categories');
   ```
2. Then change in Category model

   ```
   public function products()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Product','category_id');
   }
   ```

3.Then get all categories with products list

```
use App\Category   
             // include category model where you want to call this function
Category::with('products')->get();
```